# Finalise SQLite 3 statement

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using Windows 8 release preview and C#(VS 2012), I'm new to SQLite, I integrated SQLite 3.7.13 in my App and it is working fine, Observe my code below

```
var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Test.db");
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{                       
    var data = db.Table<tablename>().Where(tablename => tablename.uploaded_bool == false && tablename.Sid == 26);
    try
    {
        int iDataCount = data.Count();
        int id;                        
        if (iDataCount > 0)
        {                  
            for (int i = 0; i < iDataCount; i++)
            {
                Elements = data.ElementAt(i);
                id = Elements.id;
                /*
                Doing some code
                */                                               
            }     
             int i = db.Delete<tablename>(new tablename() { Sid = 26 });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

where "Sid" is column in my database and with number "26" i will get n number of rows
So, using a for loop i need to do some code and after the for loop I need to delete records  of Sid(26) in database, So at this line

```
int i = db.Delete<tablename>(new tablename() { Sid = 26 });
```

I'm getting `unable to close due to unfinalised statements` exception, So my question is how to finalise the statement in sqlite3,Apparently SQLite3 has a finalize method for destroying previous DB calls but I am not sure how to implement this. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the covers sqlite-net does some amazing things in an attempt to manage queries and connections for you.

For example, the line

```
var data = db.Table<tablename>().Where(...)
```

Does not actually establish a connection or execute anything against the database. Instead, it creates an instance of a class called TableQuery which is enumerable.

When you call

```
int iDataCount = data.Count();
```

TableQuery actually executes

```
GenerateCommand("count(*)").ExecuteScalar<int>();
```

When you call

```
Elements = data.ElementAt(i);
```

TableQuery actually calls

```
return Skip(index).Take(1).First();
```

**Take(1).First()** eventually calls **GetEnumerator**, which compiles a SQLite command, executes it with TOP 1, and serializes the result back into your data class.

So, basically, every time you call **data.ElementAt** you are executing another query. This is different from standard .NET enumerations where you are just accessing an element in a collection or array.

I believe this is the root of your problem. I would recommend that instead of getting the count and using a **for(i, ...)** loop, you simply do **foreach (tablename tn in data)**. This will cause all records to be fetched at once instead of record by record in the loop. That alone may be enough to close the query and allow you to delete the table during the loop. If not, I recommend you create a collection and add each SID to the collection during the loop. Then, after the loop go back and remove the sids in another pass. Worst case scenario, you could close the connection between loops.

Hope that helps.